# Use of preposition 'to'

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

I hope to understand the use of the preposition ***to*** gerunds and the overall structure of the following sentence. Normally the use of ***to*** is to specify a destination or a purpose but here the way it is used is unfamiliar to me.

---

```
The report was relentlessly hostile to the scientist,
interpreting one complex event after
another to his discredit.
```

---

I await your answers.

Comment: This is the result of merging two clauses: _The report was relentlessly hostile to the scientist_ and _The report interpreted one complex event after another to the scientist's discredit_. They could be combined in a number of ways, but this particular method makes an adverbial participial phrase out of the second sentence by (1) using a present participle verb form (_interpreting_) in the second clause, (2) deleting the repeated subject (_the report_) of that clause, and (3) placing the resulting phrase at the end of the first sentence with a comma splice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*to* has multiple meanings when used as a preposition. In my computer's dictionary (Oxford American, I believe), there are 7 definitions. Definition #1 refers to direction (with a number of different senses), definition #2 is:

```
identifying the person or thing affected
```

In your example sentence, the second definition applies to both uses. The origin is presumably metaphoric from the first definition: rather than a thing moving in a direction, it refers to the direction of an abstract effect, e.g. hostility flows from the report toward the scientist.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the preposition "to" begins an adverbial clause describing how (in which manner) the complex events were interpreted. It is similar to the directional use of "to" , if you think of impact or effect as an emotional destination; at the very least it is an effect, and a change.